# Can't install softKEYBOARD from samples

Tags: android

I'm trying to play around with the software keyboard example that comes with the SDK...

To get it into a new project, I create a new project from an existing sample, like in the screenshot below.

Yet when I try to execute it, here's what the console gives.

```
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] ------------------------------
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Android Launch!
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] adb is running normally.
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] No Launcher activity found!
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Performing sync
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Automatic Target Mode: using device '313101F4C18200EC'
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Device API version is 10 (Android 2.3.4)
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] \com_example_android_softkeyboard\bin\com_example_android_softkeyboard.apk installed on device
[2011-06-13 21:37:46 - com_example_android_softkeyboard] Done!
```

Any ideas what might be causing this problem? Thanks!

P.S. Maybe someone know of other good keyboard examples/tutorials, besides this one?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like it installed properly.  Long-press a text field and try selecting that new keyboard.

Comment: nope, only 'Android keyboard' and another one I had installed. nothing new there. :/

Answer (score 2):

The line "Application already deployed. No need to reinstall." is what you should focus on.
The rest you see is normal. This is telling you that you already have an identical version of that app installed and that you do not need to reinstall. This often happens if you install your source code, make 0 changes, and try to install it again. This will not happen if the version you have on your device/emulator differs from your source code.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with this too. Notice that at first you have to explicitly activate the newly installed IME in your settings before you can select it by long pressing. See the last point in the security section of the following link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#Security

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the existing softkeyboard from emulator using adb, then you will be able to run the new one :).